# Split Pandas Dataframe by column value with different lenght

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I have a DataFrame like this : [DATASET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3hSV.png)

I want to separate my data set into four parts.

Each of the four parts correspond to a title.

The difficulty is that each of these four parts of the table has different sizes. Moreover I don't have only one table but many others (with parts having different sizes but still four parts).

The goal is to find a way to separate my table by referring to the TITLE each time. Do you have an idea of how to do it?

Sincerely,

Etienne

Comment: We can be more helpful if you show what you have done and what is not working.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.